# Google spreadsheets API C# missing resource version id on batch update

Tags: c#, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to batch update the empty cells using the spreadsheets api C# v2.2.0.0 this way:

```
foreach (var csvline in csv)
{
          var csvlineParsed = csvline.Split(';');
          for (uint index = 0; index < csvlineParsed.Length; index++)
          {
                var cellEntry = new CellEntry(i, index + 1, csvlineParsed[index]);
                cellFeed.Insert(cellEntry);

                var cell = new CellEntry(i, index + 1);
                cell.Id = new AtomId(string.Format("{0}/{1}", cellFeed.Self, "R" + i + "C" + index + 1));
                cell.InputValue = csvlineParsed[index];
                cell.BatchData = new GDataBatchEntryData("R" + cell.Row + "C" + cell.Column, GDataBatchOperationType.update);
                batchRequest.Entries.Add(cell);*/

          }
          i++;
}

var batchResponse = (CellFeed) _service.Batch(batchRequest, new Uri(cellFeed.Batch));
```

but I have the "missing resource version id" error

Answer (score 4):

Another way I solved this is through adding an additional HTTP header

```
If-Match: *
```

Which says overwrite anything.

Comment: I am working with plain protocol and the Etag="*" did not worked, this one did as a charm.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar issue where I work. We wound up setting the `Etag` property on the CellEntry to `*` which allows the update to pass through. I'm sure it basically is letting it overwrite any value that was in the value in the cell but that's only an issue if you have a lot of concurrent processes/updates happening.

We grabbed the CellFeed and got the CellEntry's directly from it, and made our modifications including setting the Etag. After that we called `Publish()` on it which does a batch request of all the entries that are marked dirty, which happens automatically when you change something on them, or you can manually set `entry.Dirty = True`.

Some rough code to explain what we did, this just sets the cells in the first row to the strings in `values`, `cellQuery` is a CellQuery that gets the cells you want to work with.

```
CellFeed cellFeed = spreadsheetService.Query(cellQuery);
int i = 1;
foreach (string value in values)
{
   CellEntry entry = cellFeed[1, i++];
   entry.InputValue = value;
   entry.Etag = "*";
}

cellFeed.Publish();
```

You could probably make a batch request of your own and set the entities `Etag` to `*` and get the same results, but I find the `Publish()` method much easier to work with.

Comment: +1 This worked for me but in my case i used ListFeed and ListEntry together so i had to use both ListEntry.Update() and then ListFeed.Publish(); Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Because I personally had some trouble figuring out how to apply the previously suggested answers. I went to the ends of the internet to try to find how to set the extra header (If-Match: *)

So I will leave this here for you.

In my Java application this was done doing:

```
    service.setHeader("If-Match", "*")
```

In my .NET application it was done doing:

```
    ((GDataRequestFactory)service.RequestFactory).CustomHeaders.Add("If-Match: *");
```

I hope this will save some of you that were looking for this (Especially the one for the .NET version which I literally spent hours trying to find) some time.

- AydinE

Answer (score 0):

A had the same problem, and according to the documentation (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=fr-FR&csw=1#updating_multiple_cells_with_a_batch_request),

First of all you have to get the entities, cannt do it as "simple" as you are trying I think.

```
private static Dictionary<String, CellEntry> GetCellEntryMap(
    SpreadsheetsService service, CellFeed cellFeed, List<CellAddress> cellAddrs)
{
  CellFeed batchRequest = new CellFeed(new Uri(cellFeed.Self), service);
  foreach (CellAddress cellId in cellAddrs)
  {
    CellEntry batchEntry = new CellEntry(cellId.Row, cellId.Col, cellId.IdString);
    batchEntry.Id = new AtomId(string.Format("{0}/{1}", cellFeed.Self, cellId.IdString));
    batchEntry.BatchData = new GDataBatchEntryData(cellId.IdString, GDataBatchOperationType.query);
    batchRequest.Entries.Add(batchEntry);
  }

  CellFeed queryBatchResponse = (CellFeed)service.Batch(batchRequest, new Uri(cellFeed.Batch));

  Dictionary<String, CellEntry> cellEntryMap = new Dictionary<String, CellEntry>();
  foreach (CellEntry entry in queryBatchResponse.Entries)
  {
    cellEntryMap.Add(entry.BatchData.Id, entry);
    Console.WriteLine("batch {0} (CellEntry: id={1} editLink={2} inputValue={3})",
        entry.BatchData.Id, entry.Id, entry.EditUri,
        entry.InputValue);
  }

  return cellEntryMap;
}
```